# Android: Add images from url on custom suggest icon on search widget

Tags: android, search-suggestion

As the title says I want to add some images from url as icons on custom suggest on search widget. I see on [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1) on android.com that I have to use Uri but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + YOUR_APP_PACKAGE + "/" + resourceId);
```

E.g.:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mycompany.myapp/" + R.drawable.suggest_icon);
```